# Traffic from banned ip still appearing in nginx log

Tags: ufw

I created a rule using UFW which banned an ip address with the following command

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from <ip address> to any
```

Now if I try to SSH to the server from that IP address it blocks it, but if I try and access one of the websites hosted on that server it works.

I've checked the nginx access log and it shows traffic coming from the correct IP, and I have done

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

and the IP is listed as number 1 before any allow rules.

How can I solve this?

The only thing I can think of is that the particular site is behind cloudflare.  We've done the necessary changes so that the original IP address appears in the nginx log.....but UFW should block this before it reaches nginx...so is there something we need to do to UFW to get it to recognize the original source IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UFW only sees the IP address in the IP packet headers arriving to your server. Therefore it only sees the Cloudflare IP address.

In nginx it is different, because it can look into HTTP headers, where Cloudflare adds the original request IP address, and nginx can use that as the client IP address.

You cannot achieve what you want with an UFW rule. Your only alternatives are to work with nginx, or see if Cloudflare has any IP address blocking features.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I followed the tutorial here https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx- and was able to solve the problem.